# If $a$ and $b$ leave the same remainders when divided by $n$, so do $a^k$ and $b^k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that for $n\in \mathbb N, n\geq 2$:
>   $$(\forall a\in \mathbb N)(\forall b \in\mathbb N)(\forall k\in \mathbb N)( a\equiv_n b \rightarrow a^k \equiv_n b^k).$$

The definition for $a \equiv_n b$ is that we can write $a = nq_1 + r$ and $b = nq_2 + r$ where the remainders $r$ are the same.

---

(From [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557587/forall-a-in-n-forall-b-in-n-forall-k-in-n-a-equiv-nb-rightarrow-ak-equiv/1557610#comment3171331_1557587))

I know I need to use induction. Maybe separate it left side and right side. $(b-a) = n(m-k)$. $(a^k-b^k) = n(n(m-k)^k+2b(m-k))$. $n|(a^k-b^k)$ and thus $a^k=nb^2$. I don't know if I'm right or even close.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I know i need to use induction. Maybe separate it left side and right side. (b-a) = n(m-k). (a^k-b^k) = n(n(m-k)^k+2b(m-k)). n|(a^k-b^k) and thus a^k=nb^2... Dont know if Im right or even close

Comment: Hint: Equivalently we have $x\equiv_n y$ if and only if $n$ divides $x-y$.

Comment: i know what you mean, but I tried it that way and I find it difficult to manipulate

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First note that we have $x\equiv_n y$ if and only if $n$ divides $x-y$.

For the induction step, we need to show that if $a^k\equiv_n b^k$ then 
$a^{k+1}\equiv_n b^{k+1}$. We use the fact that
$$a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}=a^{k+1}-ab^k+ab^k-b^{k+1}=a(a^k-b^k) +b^k(a-b).$$

**Remark:** To do it without induction, use the identity
$$a^m-b^m=(a-b)(a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}b+\cdots +ab^{m-2}+b^{m-1}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for any integer $k\ge1$, $a-b$ is a factor of $a^k-b^k$: $$a^k-b^k=(a-b)\cdot \left(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+a^{k-3}b^2+\cdots+b^{k-1}\right).$$ However, the first factor, $a-b=(nq_1 + r)-(nq_2 + r)=n(q_1-q_2)$, is a multiple of $n$, because $a\equiv b$, and the product of it an the other factor (which is an integer) is necessarily a multiple of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a variation on the other answers, but it falls out from the more general fact that if $a\equiv_nb$ and $c\equiv_nd$, then $ac\equiv_nbd$. Proof? From $b-a=rn$ and $d-c=sn$, we get $bd-ac=b(d-c)+(b-a)c=bsn+crn=(bs+cr)n$. Now the induction is clear.